# Collect GCOV results from binaries running on different hosts

Tags: c++, ssh, profiling, code-coverage, gcov

Suppose I build my project with coverage on machine A. Copy executables of the project into machine B. Tests are run using these executables on machine B. Is there a way to collect coverage results for these runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using -fprofile-generate flag while compiling and linking.
So when you compile you will get .gcno files generated in your Machine A. Now you transfer your executables to Machine B and run the executable. This will create .gcda files in the path you have provided in -fprofile-generate flag in Machine B.

Now simply transfer your .gcda files back to Machine A(where your .gcno files are)and run gcov , it will give you the coverage report for the run on Machine B.

Hope this helps.